# Bootstrap carousel has white space between each images on iPhone 6s

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

When I view my carousel on the iPhone in portrait orientation only, it has white space between each image.  I've tried answers from other similar questions on stackoverflow, but none have worked.  Here is my test site:
http://dexydemo.com/test/

```css
#slidercontainer {
  max-width:100%;
 margin:0 auto 0 !important;
}

/*   ********************************* CAROUSEL *************************************************** */


.carousel-indicators {
 display:none;
}
 
.carousel-inner .item {
  max-height: 680px;
}

.carousel-inner .item:after {
  content: "";
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.carousel-control {
  width: 10%;
  color:#fff !important;
}

.carousel-control .fa {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 5;
  display: inline-block;
}
.carousel-control .fa.fa-chevron-right {
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: -10px;
}



/* ************************** Slider caption ************************** */

.carousel-caption {
   top: 16%;
}
  
.carousel-caption h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family:Oswald;
  font-size: 4.0vw;
  font-weight:700;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.carousel-caption p {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 2.5vw;
  margin-bottom: 2.5vw;
}

/**
 * Change animation duration
 */
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:1241px) and (max-width: 1440px) {
 
.carousel-caption {
 top:13% !important;

} 
}

@media only screen and (min-width:1111px) and (max-width: 1240px) {

.carousel-caption {
 top:10% !important;

} 
}

@media only screen and (min-width:891px) and (max-width: 1110px) {

.carousel-caption {
 top:5%;
}
}


@media only screen and (min-width:751px) and (max-width: 890px) {

.carousel-control .fa-chevron-left {
   margin-left:50% !important;
}

.carousel-control .fa.fa-chevron-right {
  right: 50% !important;
  margin-right: -10px !important;
}
 
.carousel {
    width:110% !important;
 overflow: hidden !important;
 right:10% !important;
}

.carousel-caption {
 top:-3% !important;
 right:8% !important;
}
  
.carousel-caption h2 {
  font-size: 6.2vw !important;
   margin-bottom: 15px !important;
}

.carousel-caption p {
  font-size: 4.5vw !important;
  margin-bottom: 4.8vw !important;
}

}


@media only screen and (min-width:550px) and (max-width: 750px) {

.carousel-control .fa-chevron-left {
   margin-left:50% !important;
}

.carousel-control .fa.fa-chevron-right {
  right: 50% !important;
  margin-right: -10px !important;
}
 
.carousel {
    width:110% !important;
 overflow: hidden !important;
 right:10% !important;
}

.carousel-caption {
 top:0 !important;
 right:8% !important;
}
  
.carousel-caption h2 {
  font-size: 5.0vw !important;
   margin-bottom: 15px !important;
}

.carousel-caption p {
  font-size: 4.5vw !important;
  margin-bottom: 4.8vw !important;
}

}

@media only screen and (min-width:421px) and (max-width: 549px) {
 
.carousel-control .fa-chevron-left {
   margin-left:150% !important;
}

.carousel {
    width:130% !important;
 overflow: hidden !important;
 right:30% !important;
}

.carousel-caption {
 top:0% !important;
 right:-10% !important;
}
  
.carousel-caption h2 {
  font-size: 4.8vw !important;
   margin-bottom: 15px !important;
}

.carousel-caption p {
  font-size: 4.5vw !important;
  margin-bottom: 4.8vw !important;
}

}

@media only screen and (min-width:321px) and (max-width: 420px) {

.carousel-control .fa-chevron-left {
   margin-left:150% !important;
}

.carousel {
    width:130% !important;
 overflow: hidden !important;
 right:30% !important;
}

.carousel-caption {
 top:-13% !important;
 right:-10% !important;
}

.carousel-caption h2 {
  font-size: 4.8vw !important;
   margin-bottom: 15px !important;
}

.carousel-caption p {
  font-size: 4.3vw !important;
  margin-bottom: 4.8vw !important;
}

}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px){
 
.carousel-control .fa-chevron-left {
   margin-left:150% !important;
}

.carousel {
    width:130% !important;
 overflow: hidden !important;
 right:30% !important;
}

.carousel-caption {
 top:-18% !important;
 right:-10% !important;
}

  
.carousel-caption h2 {
  font-size: 4.8vw !important;
   margin-bottom: 15px !important;
}

.carousel-caption p {
  font-size: 4.5vw !important;
  margin-bottom: 4.8vw !important;
}

}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.2.3/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="slidercontainer">

<div class="carousel slide" id="img-carousel" data-ride="carousel">

  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li class="active" data-target="#img-carousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
    <li data-target="#img-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#img-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#img-carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  
      <div class="item active"><img src="http://dexydemo.com/test/images/001.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h2 class="animated fadeInDown">Personal Injury Lawyers</h2>
        <p class="animated fadeInUp">Call</p>
        <p class="animated fadeInUp">FREE CASE REVIEW</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item"><img src="http://dexydemo.com/test/images/002.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h2 class="animated fadeInDown">We&#8217;ll Fight To Get You Money </h2>
        <p class="animated fadeInUp">Call</p>
        <p class="animated fadeInUp">FREE CASE REVIEW</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item"><img src="http://dexydemo.com/test/images/003.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h2 class="animated fadeInDown">You Pay No Fee Unless We Win</h2>
        <p class="animated fadeInUp">Call</p>
        <p class="animated fadeInUp">FREE CASE REVIEW</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to remove all empty spaces and jumps between each <div class="item"></div>

Comment: @ rgdesign, unfortunately, that did not work.